# How Much Current Is available in Series-Connected Batteries?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, series

If 3 fully charged (3.7V(nom), 2.9Ah) li-ion batteries (rated for 2A max per cell), were placed in series to form a 3S battery pack, how much current could a maximum load draw from the battery without causing damage to the cells?  2A or 6A?

Answer (score 5):

Connecting batteries in series will increase the voltage and keep current capacity constant. When you connect batteries in series :

- Vtotal = V1+V2+...+Vn (e.g. 1.5+1.5+1.5=4.5V)
- Current capacity = lowest current capacity between batteries (e.g. 2A)

Connecting batteries in parallel will increase the current and keep voltage constant.

- Vtotal = single battery voltage (e.g. 1.5V)
- Itotal capacity = Summation of all batteries current capacity (e.g. 2+2+2=6A)

You can use combination of connecting batteries in series or parallel to achieve your desired current capacity and voltage margin. This link will help you http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations

Comment: What would happen to the available current of the battery, if one of the cells was not at the same V level or charge capacity as the other 2 cells (e.g. 1 cell was 3.9V@75% charge & the other 2 cells were 4.2V@100%). The battery V would be less than 12.6V (as would be the case for 3 fully charged 4.2V cells), but how much less? How would it be calculated. Also, what about the available current and what happens exactly to the battery's output when one cell's current output is virtually nothing after it is depleted?

Comment: Series Batteris: as I mentioned total voltage is some of each battery, Vtotal = 4.2+4.2+3.9=12.3 Volt . Current capacity is equal to the lowest current capacity between batteries, as it's a property of battery, then if all batteries are same, current capacity is same as current capacity of each battery: Max Current Load = 2A

Comment: for best performance you should always use Same mark batteries and pack them together when they are full charged or full discharged. because they will charge together and discharge together in same period of time.

Comment: CC/CV charging of li-ion cells of the same manuf. capacity does not ensure the cells will have the same available charge.  The recommended CC/CV charging method for 3.7V 18650 li-ion cells tapers off to a specific charge rate (I think 50mA) & then the charger stops charging the cell/s.  What can be done to avoid one cell sputtering out before the others, other than setting a shut-off threshold within a device circuitry to prevent such a condition from occurring.  But is that good enough as the cells age?

Comment: It's exactly a known issue. You Should always connect batteries of same Type, same Manufacture, same Model and of course same Age. using an old battery in a pack will reduce performance and life time of other batteries because of their undercharging. As a battery pack age gets old, it's capacity and max current will reduce.

Comment: One last question.  Which is worse for a battery:  A.  a weaker, less charged cell in a series battery, or,  B. a weaker, less charged cell in a parallel branch of parallel+series battery (assuming the weaker cell is in one of the parallel banks)?  I know the weaker cell will bring down the V & output current of the parallel bank, but what are the overall negatives compared to a series battery?

Comment: when you connect batteries in parallel, their voltage should be same. Since batteries are not ideal, they have internal resistance that when battery gets old, it's resistance will become higher. when you connect them parallel then the internal voltage of batteries should be same,it means the damaged battery can not deliver so much current to keep its voltage equal to other batteries.We conclude that the performance of a weak battery in parallel is as it's not exist.

Comment: when you connect batteries in series their current should be same, it means a weak battery should deliver as much current as an good battery deliver, then the weak battery will discharged rapidly and it's voltage reduce fast.

Comment: What do you mean by "We conclude that the performance of a weak battery in parallel is <as it's not exist>."?  And, who is "We"?

Comment: In Parallel configuration, voltage of batteries is same and each battery deliver (according to its capacity) some amount of current. A weak battery can not deliver much current and it means if we remove this battery, total current capacity of pack remain same.

Comment: So in other words, as the cell in the parallel bank approaches total charge depletion, it would not affect the bank V when it is 100% depleted,but it would eventually cause that bank to be depleted sooner than the other banks in the battery.  When the charge of that bank is depleted, it will output less V & cause the battery to have a lower V output sooner than would occur if the bank had a good cell in it from the start. But, isn't that a better situation (would cause less problems for the other cells in the pack) than a battery that has only series-connected cells?

Comment: In a series connection, if one of batteries fails, in most cases, the device operation will be halted because of lack of voltage, it is so serious. In a parallel connection, a failed battery, will exhaust other batteries capacity and after a while , the device under operation will be halted for lack of energy.

Comment: So, is it your opinion that the weaker cell in a series configuration is worse for the battery than in a parallel configuration, or or do you think it makes no significant difference in either configuration regarding damage to other cells in the battery?

Comment: In aspect of batteries it is worse in Parallel. In aspect of powered device it is worse in series connection.

Comment: Worse in parallel because it could easily drain the other li-ion cells (perhaps many cells) below their cut-off V in a bank--which could cause explosion, damage, loss of recharge capacity and/or lost cycle life?  And, worse in series because it would cause very low V that would likely prevent a load device from operating?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In parallel configuration it will damage other batteries and in series configuration it will make trouble for load device.

Answer (score 4):

Each cell in series has to provide the full output current, so, if the maximum allowed current for one cell is 2A, then for a string of cells in series, the maximum current will be 2A. The capacity (Ah) will also be the same as for a single cell.

Comment: What would happen to the available current of the battery, if one of the cells was not at the same V level or charge capacity as the other 2 cells (e.g. 1 cell was 3.9V@75% charge & the other 2 cells were 4.2V@100%).  The battery V would be less than 12.6V (as would be the case for 3 fully charged 4.2V cells), but how much less?  How would it be calculated.  Also, what about the available current and what happens exactly to the battery's *output* when one cells current output is virtually nothing after it is depleted?

Comment: If you let one cell to be undercharged or overdischarged then you will have problems with the battery longevity. The total voltage is the sum  of all cells, so in your example, you would get 4.2+4.2+3.9=12.3V). The available current will most likely be the same, since the 75% cell should be able to provide the ful current. If one cell gets discharged and you still try to discharge the pack, then that cell will get reverse charged and will probably go bad (or in Li-Ion case - explode).

Comment: Hmm.. How does a cell get reversed charged?  The other cells will still be outputting a +V and charge (I assume via electron ripple--like an electron train of cars transferring the energy via charge force) when the depleted cell is out of charge.  How can a fully discharged cell get reverse charged?

Answer (score -1):

The battery connected in series add up voltage and maximum current draw is depends on C rating of the cell.If C rating of the cell is 2C and your capacity is 2.9 Ah then the maximum current you can draw from it is 2.9*2 =5.8 A

Comment: The OP's batteries are 2 A max. Welcome to EE.SE.